# Toshiba satellite C665 P5010 network devices not functioning in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ubuntu-10.04, toshiba-laptop

I got a brand new Toshiba Satellite C665 with Ubuntu 10.04 installed. But NetworkManager shows, 'No network devices available'. But when I ran the system testing, test detected Atheros Communications Ethernet controller.

How can I get my network devices work(both wireless and wired). Did I miss any driver during installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 10.04 doesnot have drivers for Atheros ethernet card and Broadcom wireless cards.

TO install the driver for Atheros ethernet card follow these steps

1: Download driver from  http://www.belobog2.0fees.net/AR81Family-linux-v1.0.1.14.zip.

After extracting the file, change to the extracted directory.

Please follow these steps after the above step.

> 1: sudo su 2: make install 3: modprobe atl1e 4: exit

Now, your lan must be working. Once the lan driver is installed, open

```
System > Administration > Hardware drivers
```

Now, Ubuntu will automatically install driver for wirless device.

Reply

Forward